# How can I start 2 function (turtle) at same time (PYTHON)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I just give a simple example but i want I want to understand it logic.
For example how "*I'm going to start the two together at the same time?*".

Thanks for answers..

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()

nah=turtle.Turtle() #first turtle
nah1=turtle.Turtle() #secondturtle
n=1
nah.speed(0)
nah.penup()
nah.goto(-300,200)
nah.pendown()
nah1.penup()
nah1.goto(-300,180)
nah1.pendown()

def func1():
    for i in range (4):
        nah.right(45)
        nah.forward(40)
        nah.left(45)
        nah.forward(30)
        nah.left(45)
        nah.forward(40)
        nah.right(45)
        nah.forward(30)

def func2():
    for e in range(4):
        nah1.left(45)
        nah1.forward(40)
        nah1.right(45)
        nah1.forward(30)
        nah1.right(45)
        nah1.forward(40)
        nah1.left(45)
        nah1.forward(30)

func1()
func2()


wn.exitonclick()
```

You dont mind my script i want just logic.

Answer (score 0):

To start some code in parallel with another code, create a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

The simplest example:

```
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=func1)
my_thread.start()
# start() returns immediately and the thread runs "in backgound"

func2() # runs in the main thread, in parallel with my_thread

my_thread.join() # wait for the thread to finish, if it has not already
```

### EDIT: It does not work

I tried this after posting the answer and unfortunately it does not work with Turtle. I get:

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

### A Different Approach?

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40323356/389289).

Comment: I've posted a modified thread-based approach that seems to get around the problem you were having -- see if there's anything else amiss with it if you don't mind.  I also posted an alternative approach to your generator-based solution.

Comment: @cdlane The generator solution is an improvement, but the answer with threads looks fishy ;)

Comment: I've gotten around to eliminating the fishy nature of my threads solution.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since I already gave a [bad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40323166/389289), I now feel bound to give a better one ;)

Since threads are not an option, you have to pause the execution of one function in order to run the other and then switch from one to the other.

A simple way to pause a function and then continue it later is to make a generator by *yielding* where the *pause* should be.

First, define the places to be used for pausing:

```
def func1():
    for i in range (4):
        nah.right(45)
        yield
        nah.forward(40)
        yield
        nah.left(45)
        yield
        nah.forward(30)
        yield
        nah.left(45)
        yield
        nah.forward(40)
        yield
        nah.right(45)
        yield
        nah.forward(30)
        yield

def func2():
    for e in range(4):
        nah1.left(45)
        yield
        nah1.forward(40)
        yield
        nah1.right(45)
        yield
        nah1.forward(30)
        yield
        nah1.right(45)
        yield
        nah1.forward(40)
        yield
        nah1.left(45)
        yield
        nah1.forward(30)
        yield
```

Then call the two functions interchangably until both finish:

```
import itertools

for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(func1(), func2()):
    pass
```

<sup>*In Python2, use `izip_longest` instead of `zip_longest`.</sup>

### Explanation

So, how does it work?

`func1()` anfd `func2()` now return generator objects. This would be a low-tech way of using them:

```
gen1 = func1()
gen2 = func2()

next(gen1)
next(gen2)
next(gen1)
next(gen2)
next(gen1)
next(gen2)
...
```

A generator object can be iterated and it will yield values. In this case, it just yields `None` all the time, but we are not interested at what it yields - we just want it to pause.

So, this would execute the whole `func1`:

```
for x in func1():
    pass
```

In order to interchangeably execute func1 and func2, they are zipped. `zip_longest` makes sure that the iteration does not stop when one of the functions is finished, but continues until both are finished instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this. One approach to use the screen.ontimer() event (see the turtle documentation). This approach allows you to adjust the turtles to actual clock time.

The approach I used below is to break up turtle motion into tiny steps inside a generator which yields after every bit of motion. This is similar to what @zvone did but to a much finer degree (smoother motion) and with less impact on your original code.  I've also set it up to take advantage of the existing `turtle.speed()` to control the absolute and relative speed of the two turtles -- if you say turtle1.speed("fast") it will move fast compared to a turtle2.speed("slow").

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def forward(turtle, distance):
    speed = turtle.speed()
    for _ in range(0, distance, speed):
        turtle.forward(speed)
        yield 0

def func1(turtle):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.right(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 40)
        turtle.left(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 30)
        turtle.left(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 40)
        turtle.right(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 30)

def func2(turtle):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.left(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 40)
        turtle.right(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 30)
        turtle.right(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 40)
        turtle.left(45)
        yield from forward(turtle, 30)

nah1 = Turtle(shape='turtle')  # first turtle
nah1.penup()
nah1.goto(-300, 200)
nah1.pendown()
nah1.speed('slowest')
generator1 = func1(nah1)

nah2 = Turtle(shape='turtle')  # second turtle
nah2.penup()
nah2.goto(-300, 180)
nah2.pendown()
nah2.speed(nah1.speed() + 1)  # a little faster than nah1
generator2 = func2(nah2)

def race_turtles():
    while (next(generator1, 1) + next(generator2, 1)) < 2:
        pass

screen = Screen()

screen.ontimer(race_turtles, 100)

screen.exitonclick()
```

I initiated the race inside a `screen.ontimer()` event so that the entire race takes place after the `exitonclick()` call.  This way you can click on the window to close it even while the race is running.  If we simply called `race_turtles()` directly, then clicking on the screen would do nothing until the race was over.

From Aesop's, "The Tortoise and the Slightly Faster Tortoise":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Lots of folks have this problem trying to use turtle with treading -- let's see if we can make something work.  The key change is to not allow the additional threads to manipulate the turtle -- they instead queue up their turtle requests and let the main thread process them:

```
import queue
import threading
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def forward(turtle, distance):
    graphics.put((turtle.forward, distance))

def right(turtle, angle):
    graphics.put((turtle.right, angle))

def left(turtle, angle):
    graphics.put((turtle.left, angle))

def func1():
    for _ in range(4):
        right(nah1, 45)
        forward(nah1, 40)
        left(nah1, 45)
        forward(nah1, 30)
        left(nah1, 45)
        forward(nah1, 40)
        right(nah1, 45)
        forward(nah1, 30)

def func2():
    for _ in range(4):
        left(nah2, 45)
        forward(nah2, 40)
        right(nah2, 45)
        forward(nah2, 30)
        right(nah2, 45)
        forward(nah2, 40)
        left(nah2, 45)
        forward(nah2, 30)

def process_queue():
    while not graphics.empty():
        graphic, argument = graphics.get()

        graphic(argument)

    if threading.active_count() > 1:
        screen.ontimer(process_queue, 100)

graphics = queue.Queue(1)  # size = number of hardware threads you have - 1

nah1 = Turtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)  # first turtle
nah1.speed('fastest')
nah1.penup()
nah1.goto(-300, 200)
nah1.pendown()
nah1.showturtle()

nah2 = Turtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)  # second turtle
nah2.speed('fastest')
nah2.penup()
nah2.goto(-300, 180)
nah2.pendown()
nah2.showturtle()

threading.Thread(target=func1).start()
threading.Thread(target=func2).start()

screen = Screen()

process_queue()

screen.exitonclick()
```